# zlib on z/OS USS

Tags: zlib, mainframe

Im trying to compile z/lib on z/OS USS(thats right a mainframe). ive got gmake and the c89 compiler (which im assuming is c89 standards compliant) and USS is supposed to be POSIX compliant.

But zlib seems to be tripping up on

```
struct internal_state FAR *state; /* not visible by applications */
```

with the following error(s)

```
c89 -O3 -DUSE_MMAP -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1 -D_POSIX_SOURCE   -c -o example.o example.c
ERROR CCN3277 ./zlib.h:92    Syntax error: possible missing ';' or ','?
ERROR CCN3007 ./zlib.h:92    "struct internal_state" is undefined.
ERROR CCN3166 ./zlib.h:103   Definition of function FAR requires parentheses.
ERROR CCN3276 ./zlib.h:103   Syntax error: possible missing '{'?
ERROR CCN3273 ./zlib.h:124   Missing type in declaration of gz_header.
ERROR CCN3166 ./zlib.h:126   Definition of function gz_header requires parentheses.
ERROR CCN3276 ./zlib.h:126   Syntax error: possible missing '{'?
WARNING CCN3137 ./zlib.h:1346  Declaration must declare at least one declarator, tag, or the members of an enumeration.
ERROR CCN3275 ./zlib.h:1350  Unexpected text z encountered.
ERROR CCN3282 ./zlib.h:1350  The type of the parameters must be specified in a prototype.
ERROR CCN3275 ./example.c:95    Unexpected text file encountered.
ERROR CCN3045 ./example.c:95    Undeclared identifier gzFile.
ERROR CCN3046 ./example.c:96    Syntax error.
ERROR CCN3045 ./example.c:98    Undeclared identifier file.
ERROR CCN3019 ./example.c:523   Expecting an array or a pointer to object type.
ERROR CCN3280 ./example.c:527   Function argument assignment between types "const char*" and "int" is not allowed.
CCN0793(I) Compilation failed for file ./example.c.  Object file not created.
FSUM3065 The COMPILE step ended with return code 12.
FSUM3017 Could not compile example.c. Correct the errors and try again.
gmake: *** [example.o] Error 3
```

when i progressively take out the FAR * (i think its a far pointer but im really not that sure) the errors go away. But as this is a library, im not sure what other artifacts are going to be produced by removing this.

has anybody got any ideas?

any old mainframe heads out there?

Comment: This is exactly why I dislike C/C++ preprocessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it turns out there is a previous version of zlib that compiles on USS, version 1.1.4 or close to that. Its a back level, but i presume this works because it is before the implementation of the FAR pointer in the latest code. So atm i think ive got it to work.

thanks for all your help.

Regards

Mark.

Answer (score 1):

FAR is not a C89 keyword, it is a Microsoft/Intelism and is probably #defined somewhere. If not, you need to define it as nothing:

```
#define FAR
```

However, this will probably only fix one of many problems. I would guess that the library uses some form of conditional compilation to handle things like FAR pointers - you need to read the docs to find which configuration is most suitabkle for your platform.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use xlc instead of c89 since xlc is your system default compiler but you'll still probably have issues. I'd subscribe to the MVS-OE email list, the people on it are quite helpful. The link to info about the list appears to be down now so send email to 
LISTSERV@VM.MARIST.EDU
 with the message: INFO MVS-OE

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, IBM provides a prebuilt version of zlib that includes support for the compression hardware (so-called zEDC) available on recent-vintage mainframes. See [zlib for zEnterprise Data Compression](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieac100/UsingZlibForZEnterpriseDataCompress.htm)